# Adding item 2 levels deep in Redux Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I am trying to add notes to a task object but what I have so far adds it to all the tasks. When I try different ways, it doesn't compile. The Object.assign doesn't like coming after the .push()

When it adds to all task:

```
 let taskReducer = function(tasks = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_NOTE':
      return tasks.map((task) => {
        const { notes } = task;
        const { text } = action;
        notes.push({
           text,
           id: notes.length,
         })
          return task.id === action.id ?
            Object.assign({}, { task, notes }) : task
        })
```

When it doesn't compile:

```
let taskReducer = function(tasks = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_NOTE':
      return tasks.map((task) => {
       return task.id === action.id ?
        const { notes } = task;
        const { text } = action;
        notes.push({
           text,
           id: notes.length,
         })
           Object.assign({}, { task, notes }) : task
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost never want to use `Array.push()` in a reducer, because that directly mutates the existing array, and direct mutations generally break UI updates (see the [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-not-rerendering)).  You *could* use `push()` on *a new copy* of the old array, but most examples don't use that approach.  Most of the time, the suggested approach is to use `const newArray = oldArray.concat(newValue)`, which returns a new array reference containing all the old items plus the new item.

Beyond that, keep in mind that when updating nested data immutably, *every* level of nesting needs to have a copy made and returned.

Haven't actually tested this, but I think your code needs to look roughly like this example:

```js
let taskReducer = function(tasks = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_NOTE':
            return tasks.map((task) => {
                if(action.id !== task.id) {
                    return task;
                }

                const { notes } = task;
                const { text } = action;
                const newNotes = notes.concat({id : notes.length, text});

                const newTask = Object.assign({}, task, {notes : newNotes});

                return newTask;
            }
        default : return tasks;
    }
}
```